# Automatically adding increasing transparency values to gradient stops in QGIS

Tags: qgis-3, symbology, heat-map, transparency-opacity

I have a point layer in QGIS 3.14 on which I applied a heatmap symbology based on an intensity attribute (here a price value):

[image: heatmap in QGIS]

But the heatmap colors extends all over the basemap layer, covering it all with the lowest values, here represented as a yellowish hue.

Is there a simple and automated way to apply a linearly increasing transparency from lowest to highest values of the heatmap colors so that the basemap layer stays visible in regions where the intensity is low?

E.g. something like this:

[image: transparency added to lowest intensity values]

In order to achieve the above result, I actually had to tweak the transparency values for each of the 9 first gradient stops using a +10% increment, as represented by the italic number under the first stops on this figure (0=full transparency, 100=full opacity):

[image: increasing transparency on the first gradient stops]

This can be tedious if you want to expand it linearly on *all* the gradient stops as it can be represented by the green line over the color ramp, or let's say, half of them, which I think would be enough. You would have to calculate the amount of transparency to add for each step, and doing it manually, with the (high) risk of accidentally moving a gradient stop when clicking on it.

That's why I'm searching for a way to do that simply and automatically, and of course being able to save the results so that it's reusable.

Please notice that I'm not searching to apply a global transparency.

Comment: If I was faced to this problem, I think I would create my own color ramps programmatically with a QGIS one as model.

Comment: You can just set the very first color of your color ramp to transparent to get the effect you want, see screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkCzE.png and my color ramp: https://i.stack.imgur.com/91EYf.png - or do I miss something?